# Update function onmousedown using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with a button that links to a function and updates a number value on every press using onclick. I would like to be able to hold down the button and have the number recursively updated every 200 ms or so until the button is released. I have found some methods using jquery to accomplish this but I am wondering if this is possible using only the native JavaScript library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. jQuery is written in native JavaScript, so anything jQuery can do, JavaScript can do.

Code:

```
var button = document.getElementById('inc');
var span = document.getElementById('val');
var val = 0;
var pressed = false;

var inc = function () {
  if (pressed) {
    val++;
  }
  span.textContent = val;
  setTimeout(inc, 200);
};

button.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  pressed = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  pressed = false;
});

inc();
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/dimuw/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: @user3821700 You're welcome. Remember to accept an answer by clicking the tick mark next to the answer

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different version of what [Some Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401137/some-guy) came up with

```
var button = document.getElementById('inc');
var span = document.getElementById('val');
var val = 0;
var interval = null;

var inc = function () {
  span.textContent = ++val;
};

button.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  interval = setInterval(inc,200);
  inc();
});
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  window.clearInterval(interval);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wugicesi/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I put this demo in a webpage and it is giving me an error that "button is null", any clue why that would happen?

Comment: If it thinks that button is null, then that means that there's no button with an id of `inc`.

Comment: I put this code in script tags in the head and I have a button with the id of inc but it's not recognizing it..

Comment: @Doug Can you link to the test?